Approximation and homotopy
In Differential Topology the usual strategy to discuss homotopy classes by differential means is approximation, because a manifold $M$ is a euclidean neigborhood retract (ENR) and any good approximation of a map $f:X\to M$ is homotopic to $f$. Now, consider the following situation where this does not work: a pair of manifolds $Z\subset Y$, $Z$ not closed in $Y$; more precisely, suppose that $M=Y\setminus Z$ is not locally compact, hence not a ENR and we cannot guarantee approximation implies homotopy (as far as I know). The question is to exhibit an explicit counterexample: a continuous map $f:X\to M$ which is not homotopic to its smooth close approximations.
To give some concrete example, suppose $Y=\mathbb R^4$, $\dim(Z)=1$ to have enough room for manipulations. We recall $Z$ is not closed in $\mathbb R^4$, even more, $M=\mathbb R^4\setminus Z$ is not locally compact. The typical transversality attempt to show $M=Y\setminus Z$ is simply connected would be as follows:
(1) Every continuous loop $f:\mathbb S^1\to M$ can be arbitrarily approximated by a smooth loop $g:\mathbb S^1\to\mathbb R^4$ transversal to $Z$ (note the codomain of $g$ is not $M$), and since cod$(Z)\ge2$ transversality means $g$ does not meet $Z$ and so actually $g:\mathbb S^1\to M$.
(2) Now, $g$ is nulhomotopic by the smooth homotopy $H_t=(1-t)g+ta$ for any fixed $a\notin Z$. Again, we can approximate $H$ by a new smooth homotopy $\widetilde H$ transversal to $Z$, and since $H_0=f$ and $H_1\equiv a$ are already transversal to $Z$ (they do not meet $Z$!), we can preserve $\widetilde{H_0}=H_0$ and $\widetilde{H_1}=H_1$. Finally since cod$(Z)\ge3$, transversality means $\widetilde H$ does not meet $Z$, and so $\widetilde H$ is a homotopy in $M$, and $g$ is nullhomotopic in $M$.
Summing up, $f$ is arbitrarily close to $g$ and $g$ is nulhomotopic, but we cannot conclude $f$ is nulhomotopic, because approximation does not imply homotopy. Hence a more concrete version of my question above: there is a smooth curve $Z$ not closed in $\mathbb R^4$ whose complement is not simply connected?

For your "concrete" question the answer is negative, one uses the same Baire Category argument as in the 2nd answer here. By the way, in the 1st paragraph of OP it should be $M=Y\setminus Z$.

Right, the argument work in greater generality. I will write an answer in a little while.

As requested, I will answer your last ("concrete") question. In fact, I will prove more:
Theorem. Let $h: M\to N$ be a smooth map of an $m$-manifold to an $n$-manifold, where $n-m=k\ge 2$. Suppose that $N$ is $k-2$-connected. Then $C:=N\setminus h(M)$ is also  $k-2$-connected.
Proof. I will equip $N$ with a background metric. Suppose that $f: \partial B^{k-1}\to C$ is a (continuous) map. I will prove existence of a (continuous) extension of $f$ to $B=B^{k-1}$. For a subset $N'\subset N$ let $C^0(B, \partial B; N')$ denote the space of continuous extensions of $f$ to maps $B\to N'$, equipped with topology of uniform convergence. Since $N$ is $k-2$-connected, the space $C^0(B, \partial B; N)$ is nonempty.
I will prove that $C^0(B, \partial B; C)$ is nonempty by proving that it is a $G_\delta$-subset.
Let $(M_i)_{i\in \mathbb N}$ denote an exhaustion of $M$ by a compact codimension zero submanifolds with (smooth) boundary. Set $N_i:= N\setminus h(M_i)$; this is an open subset of $N$. By smooth approximation and transversality, every continuous extension $f$ to a map $B\to N$  is a $C^0$-uniform limit of maps $B^{k-1}\to N_i$. Thus, the subset $C^0(B, \partial B; N_i)$ is open and dense in $C^0(B, \partial B; N)$. But
$$
C^0(B, \partial B; C)= \bigcap_{i\ge 1} C^0(B, \partial B; N_i). 
$$
Hence, $C^0(B, \partial B; C)$ is $G_\delta$-subset, therefore, is nonempty by the Baire Theorem. qed
Note: This proof is inspired by the argument in the 2nd answer here.

Thanks, you have written it very clearly. Technical details (approximation and transversality) are straightforward and your improved formulación is the best I can imagine.
